# Error in R package installation "This version of R is not set up to install source packages"

Tags: r

I want to download topGO by biocManager. Then I was faced with compilation failed for package ‘SparseM’. I tried to upgrade gcc with brew. However, after upgrade, I can not install any packages.

```
> install.packages("shiny")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : This version of R is not set up to install source packages
If it was installed from an RPM, you may need the R-devel RPM
Warning message:
In .rs.normalizePath(libPaths) :
  path[2]="/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.1/lib/R/library": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue with RStudio after a `brew upgrade` command on a terminal.
I simply had to restart RStudio and it worked fine.